# How to install Py-Moneyed?

Tags: python, django, pip, python-module

I'm trying to add **MoneyField** to my Django App using [Django-Money](https://github.com/jakewins/django-money).

According to the requirements, I need to install **[py-moneyed](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed)** v0.4 or later.

I checked **py-moneyed** but it doesn't mention how to install py-moneyed?

Can someone help me to install **py-moneyed** and **Django-Money** on my environment ?
Is there a `pip` or `easy_install` package that will do this?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install py-moneyed`?

Comment: @J0HN - problem solved, thanks. pip install py-moneyed and pip install Django-Money worked.

Comment: Should have worked by just issuing `pip install Django-Money`. pip is specifically designed to simplify package management, one aspect of which is resolving package dependencies automatically. Please read the documentation on tools you are using.

Comment: @J0HN - Please post your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running:

```
pip install py-moneyed
```

or

```
easy_install py-moneyed
```

---

If `pip` and `easy_install` do not work, download the source for py-moneyed from their [GitHub](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed) by clicking on the 'Download Zip' button on the right side of the website.

Once you have downloaded the source, run `setup.py` inside the folder with this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install the module. For more information see Python's Docs on [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/install/).